# Issues while Setting up hyperledger fabric 2.0 in different container ports (Testing & Devlopment)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been working on Hyperledger fabric 2.0 Multi-Org Networking running under default ports. The setup is as follows:

```
Org1 ( Peer0:7051, Peer1:8051, CA: 7054 ,couchdb0:5984, couchdb1:6984:5984)
Org2 ( Peer0:9051, Peer1:10051, CA: 8054,couchdb2:7984:5984, couchdb3:8984:5984)
Orderer (0rderer1:7050, Orderer2:8050, Orderer3: 9050) RAFT Mechanism
```

The requirement is to redefine all the container ports mentioned above so that I can run the same Fabric application as two environments ( One for Testing(Stable version) and one for Development )
I tried to change the ports (Specifying environmental variables for ports in docker-compose) of Peers, orderers, CA. But I don't have any option for the CouchDB which always has the default port(5984)

Is there any way to achieve this? so that it will also be helpful in running two different fabric applications in the same virtual machine

**EDIT1:**
My docker-compose.yaml file (I have only mentioned for- Org1(Peer0,peer1), Orderer1,ca-org1, couchdb0,couchdb1)

```
version: "2"

networks:
  test2:

services:
  ca-org1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.test.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.test.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/priv_sk
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/tlsca.org1.test.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/priv_sk
    ports:
      - "3054:3054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.test.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.test.com/tlsca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls
    container_name: ca.org1.test.com
    hostname: ca.org1.test.com
    networks:
      - test2

  orderer.test.com:
    container_name: orderer.test.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.1
    dns_search: .
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=info
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_METRICS_PROVIDER=prometheus
      - ORDERER_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:3443
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=3050
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderers
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 3050:3050
      - 3443:3443
    networks:
      - test2
    volumes:
      - ./channel/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/genesis.block
      - ./channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/test.com/orderers/orderer.test.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ./channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/test.com/orderers/orderer.test.com/tls:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls

  couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0-test
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 1984:1984
    networks:
      - test2

  couchdb1:
    container_name: couchdb1-test
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 2984:1984
    networks:
      - test2

  
  peer0.org1.test.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.test.com
    extends:
      file: base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP

      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=artifacts_test2

      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.test.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.test.com:3051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:3051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.test.com:3052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:3052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.test.com:4051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.test.com:3051

      # - CORE_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9440

      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0-test:1984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
      - CORE_METRICS_PROVIDER=prometheus
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0
    ports:
      - 3051:3051
    volumes:
      - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.test.com/peers/peer0.org1.test.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.test.com/peers/peer0.org1.test.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./channel/:/etc/hyperledger/channel/
    networks:
      - test2

  peer1.org1.test.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.test.com
    extends:
      file: base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP

      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=artifacts_test2

      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.test.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.test.com:4051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:4051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org1.test.com:4052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:4052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.test.com:4051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.test.com:3051

      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb1-test:1984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
      - CORE_METRICS_PROVIDER=prometheus
      # - CORE_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9440
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
    ports:
      - 4051:4051
    volumes:
      - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.test.com/peers/peer1.org1.test.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.test.com/peers/peer1.org1.test.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./channel/:/etc/hyperledger/channel/
    networks:
      - test2
```

Thanks for the suggestions regarding couchDB. I had a thought that we should only specify the default couchDB port each instance. Anyway I missed the step of changing the container name in the first place (default peer0.org1.example.com to peer0.org1.test.com) I was able to start the docker containers with new container names so that it doesn't stop(recreate) the existing containers which is already running on the actual ports.
The issue which I am facing now is peer is not able to communicate with the couchdb-test url

```
U 04c Entering VerifyCouchConfig()
2020-08-12 11:22:45.010 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 04d Entering handleRequest()  method=GET  url=http://couchdb1-test:1984/  dbName=
2020-08-12 11:22:45.010 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 04e Request URL: http://couchdb1-test:1984/
2020-08-12 11:22:45.011 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 04f Retrying couchdb request in 125ms. Attempt:1  Error:Get "http://couchdb1-test:1984/": dial tcp 172.27.0.11:1984: connect: connection refused
2020-08-12 11:22:45.137 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 050 Retrying couchdb request in 250ms. Attempt:2  Error:Get "http://couchdb1-test:1984/": dial tcp 172.27.0.11:1984: connect: connection refused
2020-08-12 11:22:45.389 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 051 Retrying couchdb request in 500ms. Attempt:3  Error:Get "http://couchdb1-test:1984/": dial tcp 172.27.0.11:1984: connect: connection refused
```

Hence if I try to create a channel, peer container exits even though it was running till now and it's not able to join the channel

```
2020-08-12 10:58:29.264 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2020-08-12 10:58:29.301 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Expect block, but got status: &{NOT_FOUND}
2020-08-12 10:58:29.305 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2020-08-12 10:58:29.506 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 004 Expect block, but got status: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
2020-08-12 10:58:29.509 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 005 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2020-08-12 10:58:29.710 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 006 Expect block, but got status: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
2020-08-12 10:58:29.713 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 007 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2020-08-12 10:58:29.916 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 008 Expect block, but got status: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
2020-08-12 10:58:29.922 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 009 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2020-08-12 10:58:30.123 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 00a Expect block, but got status: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
2020-08-12 10:58:30.126 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 00b Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2020-08-12 10:58:30.327 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 00c Expect block, but got status: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
2020-08-12 10:58:30.331 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 00d Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2020-08-12 10:58:30.534 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 00e Received block: 0
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to localhost:3051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:53668->127.0.0.1:3051: read: connection reset by peer"
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to localhost:4051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:60724->127.0.0.1:4051: read: connection reset by peer"
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to localhost:5051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:57948->127.0.0.1:5051: read: connection reset by peer"
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to localhost:6051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58976->127.0.0.1:6051: read: connection reset by peer"
2020-08-12 10:58:37.518 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2020-08-12 10:58:37.552 UTC [channelCmd] update -> INFO 002 Successfully submitted channel update
2020-08-12 10:58:37.685 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2020-08-12 10:58:37.763 UTC [channelCmd] update -> INFO 002 Successfully submitted channel update
```

Here, only the Orderers are successfully added to the channel but not the peers even after changing the ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isnt an issue, you can just specify it as you did for the others like this. Are you facing some specific issues while mapping the ports

```
ports:
  - 6984:5984 # Mapping Host Port to Container Port
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion .Anyway I have updated my question right now. .

Comment: Sanjay did you verify that the ports you are trying to connect the CouchDB to is open?

Comment: Previously I didn't open any ports in the VM Network Configuration, but still it was working.I had to open ports only when I need to access them externally (For restAPI or Hyperledger Explorer) . I will give one more try though. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear in my last comment. I meant if you checked that the port number being used has not already been used for some other service. I hope there is no port conflict going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the couchDb port from the docker-compose file.
Showing a snippet from `docekr-compose.yaml` file.

```
  couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0
    image: couchdb:2.3
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn
```

From here you can change ports easily.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion . Anyway I have updated my question right now.